# xslt split 1 html into n html

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a large number of files with a structure like the following a.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc1
        <div class="d">ddd11
          <div class="e">eee11</div>
          <div class="f">fff11
            <div class="g">ggg111</div>
            <div class="g">ggg112</div>
            <div class="g">ggg113</div>
            <div class="g">ggg114</div>
            <div class="g">ggg115</div>
            <div class="g">ggg116</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">ccc2
        <div class="d">ddd21
          <div class="e">eee21</div>
          <div class="f">fff21
            <div class="g">ggg211</div>
            <div class="g">ggg212</div>
            <div class="g">ggg213</div>
            <div class="g">ggg214</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The number of div class="c" is a known single-digit integer, in this case it is equal to 2.

I would like to generate the files a_1.html and a_2.html, where each file contains the 1st and the 2nd occurrence of the div class="c" respectively.

In this example, I would like to generate a_1.html and a_2.html as follows:

a_1.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc1
        <div class="d">ddd11
          <div class="e">eee11</div>
          <div class="f">fff11
            <div class="g">ggg111</div>
            <div class="g">ggg112</div>
            <div class="g">ggg113</div>
            <div class="g">ggg114</div>
            <div class="g">ggg115</div>
            <div class="g">ggg116</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

a_2.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc2
        <div class="d">ddd21
          <div class="e">eee21</div>
          <div class="f">fff21
            <div class="g">ggg211</div>
            <div class="g">ggg212</div>
            <div class="g">ggg213</div>
            <div class="g">ggg214</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..2}
do
  xsltproc --param occurrence ${i} a.xslt a.html > a_${i}.html
done
```

My a.xslt however does not extract just the i-th (first or second in this case) occurrence of div class="c".

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="occurrence"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='a']" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | div[@class='b']  | text()" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='c']" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How could I modify it to get the correct result?

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `xquery` if you are only interested in XSLT?

Comment: -1 for consequent misuse of tags (I already removed a [tag:xquery] just hours ago, and left a notice). Don't use the wrong tags, applying the wrong tags alerts (and annoys) people without interest in your question.

Comment: Oops, sorry, new to this site. I didn't know of the notices counter on the top bar. I can see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to stay with your current approach, you need only to change the call for `select="div[@class='c']`.
To:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='c'][position()=$occurrence]" />
```

But attention: 
The  `<xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='a']" />` before `apply-templates` for attributes (`@*`) is wrong.
Therefor try:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | div[@class='b']  | text()" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='c'][position()=$occurrence]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the missing piece of the puzzle :) And thank you for your correction, it was very appreciated (I'm still finding my way through xslt)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:param name="occurrence"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='c']">
   <xsl:variable name="pos">
     <xsl:number count="div[@class = 'c']"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:if test="$pos = $occurrence">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Martin. I have used the suggestion from the first answer, but I can see what you are doing there. Very appreciated.